# Can BURG Boot Manager be installed on 15.10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

It appears that BURG is no longer supported on newer Ubuntu versions. I have just done a fresh install of 15.10 alongside Windows 10 and would love to have the impressive looking BURG Boot Manager open on startup. I have tried GRUB Customizer but it just does not compare.

Otherwise, are there any other options for a boot manager that is aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you would consider "aesthetically pleasing". Does it need to be GUI based? Colorful? 3-D animated? What?

Answer (score 1):

I an unfamiliar with BURG, but recommend checking out rEFInd.  It supports multiple OS X, Windows, and Linux installations on the same machine, provides a nice pretty menu, and cures some of the ailments of the now defunct rEFIt project.  It only works on the newer EFI and UEFI hardware, so older (pre-Windows 8) hardware will not support it.

Here is a link to the project:

[rEFInd Project Page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Answer (score 1):

BURG is now available for Ubuntu **15.10** in Nate Muench's Burg [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/burg/+packages).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
sudo burg-install /dev/sda
sudo update-burg
```

GRUB Customizer can be used to customize Burg/Grub, refer this [page](http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html).